# Tensorflow on Raspberry Pi 3 make error

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi3, protocol-buffers

I have been attempting a fresh install of Tensorflow on my Raspberry Pi 3 and have been running into an issue I can't solve.

I am following the guide [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile#raspberry-pi) and have been able to complete all of the steps up until the `make -f tensorflow/contrib/makefile/Makefile HOST_OS=PI TARGET=PI OPTFLAGS="-Os" CXX=g++-4.8` command.

However when attempting to run this command I am left with several errors.
The full output is rather long, but the main recurring error is similar to:

```
test_log.pb.cc:(.text+0x784): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::fixed_address_empty_string'
```

This kind of error is repeated several times throughout the output for the make -f command with `test_log.pb.cc:(.text+0x784):` being replaced with different designations. The output ends with the Following error state:

```
step_stats_collector.cc:(.text+0x46c): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::fixed_address_empty_string'
/home/pi/makevoicedemo/tf/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/libtensorflow-core.a(debug_io_utils.o):debug_io_utils.cc:(.text+0x8e8): more undefined references to `google::protobuf::internal::fixed_address_empty_string' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
tensorflow/contrib/makefile/Makefile:501: recipe for target '/home/pi/makevoicedemo/tf/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/bin/benchmark' failed
make: *** [/home/pi/makevoicedemo/tf/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/bin/benchmark] Error 1
```

I feel like the problem is likely do to an error with protobuf, however I am using the latest version and had no errors installing it. I am using the most recent version of tensorflow and followed the Before you start section in the guide to make sure all dependencies were installed and up to date.

What exactly might be causing this error and how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: For build related questions, better to file an issue in the github repo: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new

Comment: I too have this issue